Where to stroce credentials for lfs server?
currently I store my credentials in .lfsconfig file and I pushed this file to the repo so that everybody can pull from git lfs server, but this solution does not satisfy me. Other people who have access to this server, have their credentials so they should them, not mine, and of course, this solution is not safe. So I am looking for other ideas where to store these credentials so all who have access, can pull from it without pushing .lfscofnig to remote repo. I tried storing env variables but git does not have access to it, I also set URL path to lfs server in .gitconfig but it overrides the normal github git lfs server so if somebody works with different repo and uses the standard git lfs it won't work.
